# Regex in a multilingual query not working for application, but in SQL developer and unit test

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle, multilingual

I have a strange behaviour for the following query containing a regular expression:

```
SELECT COALESCE(lang.TITLE, ids.message_id) AS TEXT,
  ids.message_id
FROM
  (SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN regexp_instr(messages.NR, '[a-z]{2}[[:space:],_-]\d+[-_]\d{2,6}') > 0
      THEN regexp_substr(messages.NR, '\d+')
      ELSE messages.NR
    END AS message_id
  FROM
    ( SELECT 'GB 28647854-04' AS NR FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'GB 5310031-05' AS NR FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT '9184' AS NR FROM dual
    ) messages
  ) ids,
  LOCAL_TITLES lang  
WHERE ids.message_id = '' || lang.NUMBER_NO(+);
```

The `LOCAL_TITLES` contains the following entries:

- 5310031 | Some localized Text
- 9184    | Another Text

So the **expected query result** should be:

- 28647854      | 28647854
- Some localized Text | 5310031
- Another Text        | 9184

This works well, when the query runs via SQL Developer. Also I have a (Unit-/Integration-) Test for my DAO, which runs this query returning the expected result.

**My problem:** when the query is executed by the running web application, then the regex does not find the numeric id. Instead, the **actual query result** is

- GB 28647854-04      | GB 28647854-04
- GB 5310031-05       | GB 5310031-05
- Another Text        | 9184

Do you have an idea, why the regular expression behaves differently, when it's coming from the web application?

Comment: Doesn't your web application use the DAO to access the data? Since the DAO seems to work (at least your tests seem to indicate that) it should be fine. Thus you either execute that query/expression in some other way or your test has a different setup somehow. In any case we probably need more information.

Comment: The setup is indeed a little different for the `java.sql.Connection` implementation: the web application utilizes a `PooledConnection`, whereas during the test runs we call `DriverManager.getConnection()`. Other than that, there is no difference in the implementation. The web application runs on Weblogic 12c Server.

Comment: Note that it might not only be a difference in the implementation but also in configuration, libraries (e.g. a different JDBC driver) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is looking for lower-case characters with the `[a-z]` pattern. Your dual-generated data has upper-case GB, so they don't match, with default case-sensitive settings, at least in my locale:

```
alter session set nls_sort = 'BINARY';

SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN regexp_instr(messages.NR, '[a-z]{2}[[:space:],_-]\d+[-_]\d{2,6}') > 0
      THEN regexp_substr(messages.NR, '\d+')
      ELSE messages.NR
    END AS message_id
  FROM
    ( SELECT 'GB 28647854-04' AS NR FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'GB 5310031-05' AS NR FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT '9184' AS NR FROM dual
    ) messages;

MESSAGE_ID   
--------------
9184          
GB 28647854-04
GB 5310031-05
```

If you make the session case-insensitive they do:

```
alter session set nls_sort = 'BINARY_CI';

SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN regexp_instr(messages.NR, '[a-z]{2}[[:space:],_-]\d+[-_]\d{2,6}') > 0
      THEN regexp_substr(messages.NR, '\d+')
      ELSE messages.NR
    END AS message_id
  FROM
    ( SELECT 'GB 28647854-04' AS NR FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 'GB 5310031-05' AS NR FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT '9184' AS NR FROM dual
    ) messages;

MESSAGE_ID   
--------------
9184          
28647854      
5310031
```

You can also make it case-insensitive just within each regex call:

```
SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN regexp_instr(messages.NR, '[a-z]{2}[[:space:],_-]\d+[-_]\d{2,6}', 1, 1, 0, 'i') > 0
      THEN regexp_substr(messages.NR, '\d+', 1, 1, 'i')
      ELSE messages.NR
    END AS message_id
...
```

Or just expand the character class:

```
      WHEN regexp_instr(messages.NR, '[a-zA-Z]{2}[[:space:],_-]\d+[-_]\d{2,6}') > 0
```

or

```
      WHEN regexp_instr(messages.NR, '[[:alpha:]]{2}[[:space:],_-]\d+[-_]\d{2,6}') > 0
```

Some of your sessions are being created with BINARY_CI (or some other case-insensitive) [linguistic comparison](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm) settings, but your 'web application' setting is not. That may be down to the locale being used for each, so changing the application locale could also fix the discrepancy; but making the pattern more logical is probably better.

More specifically in your case (having looked at your profile), if your locale is Germany then your NLS_SORT with be German, which behaves the same as BINARY_CI does for me with a UK locale. Presumably your SQL Developer and unit test is being run with German settings, and your web app is not, either because of its own defaults or by design.

[Read more about "SQL Regular Expressions in a Multilingual Environment" in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG0052).